# Delay ERROR - RC Circuit

Tags: capacitor, current, comparator, inrush-current

I have designed this circuit to measure the current on the load and the comparator trips when the current of 1.2 A exceeds for 2ms.This works fine with simulation.When I build this circuit,my circuit trips within 1 ms instead of 2ms.
I am not sure what goes wrong .Is this due to the inrush current?
[image]

Comment: Consider that the cold resistance of an incandescent  lamp is about 10% of the hot resistance, and that the lamp's thermal inertia will keep its resistance low (and changing) for some time after the +12 is turned on, and there's your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have a reference voltage of 0.756V on the inverting input (derived from 5V) and therefore you should expect the circuit to "trip" when there is 0.756V on the inverting input. This is equivalent to a current of 0.756 amps through the 1 ohm resistor (R5). So, in fact, you can expect a current equal to or greater than this to eventually cause the comparator to trip.

Is this what you are wanting to happen?

Anyway, inrush current due to the lamp having a lower cold resistance can certainly make the circuit trip sooner. Other problems may be around the comparator - you haven't specified it but input offset voltages and bias currents can all make small errors but, is the comparator capable of working with the signals shown - this depends on how power is connected to the supply pins.

Comment: :I have used LM2903 Comparator with 5V SUPPLY and Gnd.Here is the link for the datasheet:http://www.ti.com/product/LM2903/datasheet.

Comment: @Andyaaka: I have set my delay as 2ms using RC Circuit.When the current of 1.2 A passes through the sense resistor,it produces the output of 1.2V but my comparator sees 0.76 V after 2ms.Then the comparator trips.This is my understanding. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: An RC is not a fixed delay - if the current is substantially bigger than the expected 1.2 amps the so-called "delay" might be less than 0.2 ms. You shouldn't rely on RC giving a fixed delay because they don't. The LM2903 is OK btw.